# How to remove elements from json, while parsing from xml using java

Tags: java, json, xml

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><type><direct num=3></direct></type><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

I can remove elements after conversion from xml to json. But actually what i needed is that, the elements  or attributes should be removed during conversion itself.

My required output is:

```
{
  "users": {
    "report": {
      "score": 30
    },
    "type": {
      "direct": {
        "num": 3
      }
    },
    "user": {
      "age": 20
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML` class does not provide methods to exclude tags. One possible solution is update the string to remove tags as below,

e.g to exclude `type` tag,

```
String splits[] = xmlString.split("(<\\/type>|<type>)");
xmlString = splits[0]+splits[2];

JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output:

> {"users":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}

To remove name element from user tag,

```
String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><type><direct num=3></direct></type><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";

//split by user tags
String splits[] = xmlString.split("(<\\/user>|<user )");

//remove name filed and combine other elements
String user1 = Arrays.stream(splits[1].split(" "))
        .filter(s->!s.contains("name"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

//merge strings and user tag
xmlString = splits[0] + "<user " + user1 + "</user>" + splits[2];

JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

Output::

```
{
    "users": {
        "report": {
            "sub": "eng",
            "score": 30
        },
        "type": {
            "direct": {
                "num": 3
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "age": 20
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
The best solution would be to remove from `JsonObject`,

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("name")
```

Comment: Can u specify whether u used any libraries? This code gives me error: Arrays, collectors cant be resolved

Comment: Those are java-8 features.

Comment: That was my mistake.. When i imported the array, it got worked.

Comment: could u show me a code to remove the 'sub' element or 'num' element of the above problem

Comment: You can follow the same steps, instead of user use report and instead of name use sub

Comment: I tried that steps and unfortunately the result was not as expected. Thats why i think this step will not work for child elemnts. the result was                 {"users":{"report":[{"score":30},{"sub":"eng","score":30}],"type":{"direct":{"num":3}}}}

Comment: `jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("type").getJSONObject("direct"). remove("num");`

I would suggest you to read about JSON traversing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217589/discussion-between-my-doubt-and-code-mode).

Answer (score 0):

org.json.XML package doesn't provide internal XML modifications. If you must use this, you have to make the necessary modifications in the json by yourself. Else you can preprocess the xml using java default xml parser, convert it to string and then convert it to json.

Comment: What i tried is, removing elements from json after processing. But to reduce the steps, i am not permitted to do so.

Comment: I dont knw to remove things while parsing.. Could u pls explain?

Comment: are you allowed to use xml parser as a pre processing step? Also do your input always a XML? If yes, I can provide you how to parse and edit an XML, otherwise you need to do string modifications as mentioned below.

Comment: to reduce the steps, you won't need many steps to remove from JSON which in this case would be a perfect solution. ```jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("name")```